# TSQL Case Statement Update Table

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to set up what I think needs to be a case statement on my stored procedure

Depending on the value of @status, I need to only update a specific column in the table.

For example: If @status = 'Approved' then I need to update the approvalDate field; same with the @status being 'Denied' I need to enter the current date into the denial field.

How would I approach this?

```
 UPDATE  tuitionSubmissions
        SET reimbursementDate = NullIf (@reimbursementDate, '1 jan 1900'),
            empGradDate       = NullIf (@gradDate, '1 jan 1900'),
            payPeriod         = NullIF (@payPeriod, '1 jan 1900'),
            [status]          = @status,
            notes             = @notes,
            managerApproval   = @empID,
            denialDate        = GETDATE(),   
            approvalDate      = GETDATE()
    WHERE   id = @tid;
```

Comment: You could get creative, and use a combination of NullIfs to solve the problem, but in the interests of keeping the code clean and maintainable, I think you should write separate `UPDATE`s for each type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 UPDATE  tuitionSubmissions
        SET reimbursementDate = NullIf (@reimbursementDate, '1 jan 1900'),
            empGradDate       = NullIf (@gradDate, '1 jan 1900'),
            payPeriod         = NullIF (@payPeriod, '1 jan 1900'),
            [status]          = @status,
            notes             = @notes,
            managerApproval   = @empID,
            denialDate        = case when @status = 'Denied'then GETDATE() else  denialDate end,   
            approvalDate      = case when @status = 'Approved'then GETDATE() else  denialDate end
    WHERE   id = @tid;
```